# Non-Residential Security Deposit Laws (Commercial Lease)

Tags: rental-property, real-estate, florida, statutes

## GOAL

The goal is to review relevant statute to ensure that the law has not changed since the publication of the citation provided below.

## DEFINITIONS

In order to protect housing renters, there are many Florida statutes regarding how deposit must be returned / communicated for landlords renting to residential tenants (that live in an apartment or house).

In contrast: it would seem that commercial (business) leases are regulated differently in that "Florida has no regulations or requirements governing the return of commercial security deposits
":

[image]

Source pp.3 Florida: https://www.akerman.com/a/web/65420/Security-Deposit-Laws-Commercial-Lease-State-Comparison-Chart.pdf

## QUESTION

Assuming this is true, What is the relevant section of Florida statute governing commercial real-estate, that one would read to verify that statue has not changed and that the Akerman claim is current and the law has not changed since Akerman's 2020 report?

## UPDATE

[Chapter 83 Landlord and Tenant](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0083/0083ContentsIndex.html) defines separated statues for **Residential** and **Non Residential** categories.  The Residential section defines familiar security deposit requirements.  I would welcome any other suggested statutory reading.

Comment: You can't really provide a citation for a negative. FWIW, I am a former Akerman attorney, and on this point, I trust their analysis (which is typical of most states). And, of course, while there are no statutory protections, the common law still provides you with some rights to have the contract enforced as written.

Comment: @ohwilleke   Always good to hear from you: I think I understand the point you are making.   I have modified the question so that the community can suggest relevant statute for review.  The goal is to review relevant statute to ensure that the law has not changed since the publication of the 2020 Akerman report

Comment: My understanding is that a "commercial lease" is a lease of a property to be used for commercial purposes, that is, as a place to run a business, not a lease of an apartment or house for residential purposes by an entity in the business of renting such property. If the purpose of the lease is for one or more people to live there, it is a residential lease, not  commercial one.The terminology used in the title and body of this question is, I think, incorrect and confusing.

Comment: Please do not post images of text as you did in this question. Such images are not searchable, and not accessible to those using screen readers or similar tech. Please OCR or re-type such text. See [meta] for more on this.

Comment: @DavidSiegel  Thank you for taking the time to provide feedback.  I have updated the post to enact your suggestions: hopefully clarity is present.   I suspect that commercial is a subset of non residential.   The quote from the screen shot is re-typed in the text.